# How can I print the raw unicode in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

I am novice in Python, so maybe I can't express it well...

I got a string `'\xb9\xfe'`

I want it print in this very fashion **`'\xb9\xfe'`**, not converting to a Chinese character `'哈'`.

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a raw string literal instead:

```
r'\xb9\xfe'
```

or print the output of `repr()` of your string:

```
print(repr('\xb9\xfe'))
```

Comment: Won't that raw string be '\' 'x' 'b' '9' '\' 'x' 'f' 'e'?

Comment: @mpez0: yes, it will be. It's not clear which variant the OP really wanted here; storing the value with 8 characters or only producing that value when printing.

Comment: Why doesn't this work then? >>> a = 'asdf\u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652'
>>> a
`'asdfقُلْ'`
>>> repr(a)
`"'asdfقُلْ'"`

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: because in Python 3 you'd want to use `ascii()` instead of `repr()` if you want non-ASCII printable characters to be represented as escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is by using **s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()**

```
s = "asdf\u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652"
print(s.encode('unicode_escape').decode())
```

*Output will be:*

```
asdf\u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652
```

*This will NOT work:*

```
s = "asdf\u0642\u064f\u0644\u0652"
print(s)
print(repr(s))
```

*Output will be:*

```
asdfقُلْ
'asdfقُلْ'
```